# Django ManyToManyField restrict user to single field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying to create a model for a comment section with a like and dislike with ManyToManyField corresponding to the specific user using the below code.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """docstring for comment."""
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name = "CommentLikes", blank = True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name = "CommentDislikes", blank = True)
```

But I need to create some kind of **restriction** so that the user is not present in both fields before saving the model.

Can someone kindly help me with how to implement it?

Comment: Can you show how you are saving it

Comment: I save the data using the admin site provided by django

Comment: If so, you can add a custom clean or validation to check this before your form for this model is saved

Comment: Can you help me out with code, and how to implement it ?

Comment: You can do something like `Comment.objects.filter(likes=request.user).exists()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by checking first if the user already exists in the Likes section or vice versa.

Just keep checking before liking or disliking that the user had done the action before or not.

Use this snippet it should work.

> Check before disliking, if he exists in like section.

```
if(len(Comment.objects.all().filter(likes=request.user))==0):
   // allow him to dislike
```

> Check before Liking

```
if(len(Comment.objects.all().filter(dislikes =request.user))==0):
       // allow him to like
```

Also make sure you don't allow single user to like more than once.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but is there any other way in which we can directly assign a rule in the model to prevent from assigning in both fields ?

Like directly enforcing the rule in to model like we do for max length ...